# Question on CLA and employment contracts in Netherlands

Tags: quitting, notice-period, unions

I am currently living in the Netherlands but from the US, just found a new job and well found out I hate every thing about it. My apologies in advance if the site is more US centric and overseas questions are out of scope.

I started work with a large multinational about 2 months ago. I hate it. I want to quit and well one of my colleagues told me that I have to give three months notice. What!? Anyways I went back to my CLA (Collective labor agreement, Union ) and noticed that it does say that at someone at my level needs to give 3 months.

"Terminating the contract of employment b. three months for other employees; applies to both employer and employee."

Also I noticed the following: "1. This CLA has been entered into for the period 1 January 2015 to 31 December 2016. It will end automatically on the expiry date without requiring notice."

Ok, so I got this about 2 months ago and never encountered 3 months before in my other jobs, I guess I glossed that over when I read it since it is crazy to me. I normally voluntary give 2 weeks notice, not mandatory.

Can I use the argument that the CLA is not valid to me since I received an old expired agreement? I really want to get out of this job. I now know in the future never to sign these again or leave before the probationary period.

Thanks for your feedback and help!

Comment: Sadly I think you need to ask a lawyer about the specifics.  In the US as you know, that screw up on the dates **might** help you, not sure about the law in the Netherlands.

Comment: If you started working for the company somewhere this year (ie after the contract expired) the wrong dates probably won't help much. If you've only been there two months, you can check if you're still in probation; most jobs with a 3 month notice period will also have 3+ months of probation, during which you can quit on the spot. If not; you could always ask your manager. 3 months is there as an extreme case, but companies are usually willing to make it shorter, especially for people who haven't been around very long.

Comment: Even after the notice period, in the Netherlands as long as both parties agree the contract could be dissolved. This would require having excellent rapport with your manager and framing your 'hate' for the job delicately. Handled well this can be seen as a very professional approach but there are plenty of managers out there that will take things personally and get angry at you. A notice period of several months is very much the norm in the Netherlands though so if you are going to look for new employment here, keep that in mind!

Answer (score 3):

Your probably stuck with 3 months in Europe and UK  3 months is common for all but the most junior professional role. However if there is a probationary period you might be able to shorten the notice periods.

The CLA has probably been replaced by a more recent one (speak to your union rep) or look on the union website.

The USA is an outlier in having such short notices and a lot of your colleagues would look at someone complaining about this as unprofessional

Comment: Do you have anything to back up your answer?  Any sources?  Not down voting but I think you need to back up this answer a bit.

Comment: @MisterSortofPositive well 30 plus years of experience of working and I am also a union activist so I know the basics of how European unions

Comment: Excellent, then you should update your answer to say "based on my experience", or something along those lines.  Once you do, I will vote for it.